Как настроить Eslint в VSСode?
Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста где находятся настройки "Eslint"?
Когда я его установил, в файле "eslint.config.mjs" настроек не было, как раньше.
Там были только эти:
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";


export default [
  { languageOptions: { globals: globals.browser } },
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
]


Могу лишь привести пример, с их новыми настройками для TS у меня получилось так:
// eslint.config.js

import jsEslint from '@eslint/js'
import tsEslint from 'typescript-eslint'
import stylistic from '@stylistic/eslint-plugin'
// import globals from 'globals'

const jsRules = jsEslint.configs.recommended.rules
const tsRules = tsEslint.configs.stylisticTypeChecked
  .reduce((a, item) => ((item.rules ? (a = { ...a, ...item.rules }) : a), a), {})

export default tsEslint.config(
  {
    files: [
      'src/**/*.{ts,js}',
      'eslint.config.js',
      'vitest.config.ts'
    ],
    languageOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 'latest',
      sourceType: 'module',
      parser: tsEslint.parser,
      parserOptions: {
        project: [
          'tsconfig.json'
        ]
      }
      // Это мне не понадобилось
      // globals: { ...globals.node }
    },
    plugins: {
      '@typescript-eslint': tsEslint.plugin,
      '@stylistic': stylistic
    },
    rules: {
      ...jsRules,
      ...tsRules,
      // тут твои правила
    }
  })

А в VSCode так:
// .vscode/settings.json
{
  "eslint.runtime": "node",
  "eslint.useESLintClass": true,
  "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.mode": "problems",
  "eslint.codeActionsOnSave.rules": [
    "!no-unused-vars",
    "!@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars",
    "*"
  ],
}

